# web2py authentication error in terminal

Tags: python, macos, authentication, web2py, attributeerror

I'm new to web2py and I am trying to get the basics down.  I'm following the instructions in the manual (http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#Adding-authentication)

I downloaded the source code from web2py, cd to the web2py direction

```
`>>>`python web2py.py
```

brings up the the screen with server port 8000 and my password...i enter it and the start the server which brings me to the website as expected

I create another tab in my terminal where I cd to the web2py directory. run python

```
from gluon import *
from gluon.tools import *

db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite')

auth = Auth(db)
```

my db is fine when I >>>db._uri or >>>db._dbname but when I try auth = Auth(db) I get an error:

```
>>> auth = Auth(db)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "gluon/tools.py", line 1268, in __init__
    request = current.request
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'request'
```

but if I dir(Auth), it seems to have imported correctly:

```
>>> dir(Auth)
['_Auth__get_migrate', '_HTTP', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_login_settings', '_get_user_id', '_reset_two_factor_auth', 'accessible_query', 'add_group', 'add_membership', 'add_permission', 'archive', 'basic', 'cas_login', 'cas_validate', 'change_password', 'default_messages', 'default_settings', 'define_signature', 'define_tables', 'del_group', 'del_membership', 'del_permission', 'email_reset_password', 'enable_record_versioning', 'get_or_create_key', 'get_or_create_user', 'get_vars_next', 'groups', 'has_membership', 'has_permission', 'here', 'id_group', 'impersonate', 'is_impersonating', 'is_logged_in', 'log_event', 'login', 'login_bare', 'login_user', 'logout', 'navbar', 'not_authorized', 'profile', 'random_password', 'register', 'register_bare', 'request_reset_password', 'requires', 'requires_login', 'requires_membership', 'requires_permission', 'requires_signature', 'reset_password', 'reset_password_deprecated', 'retrieve_password', 'retrieve_username', 'run_login_onaccept', 'table_cas', 'table_event', 'table_group', 'table_membership', 'table_permission', 'table_user', 'update_groups', 'url', 'user_group', 'user_group_role', 'user_id', 'verify_email', 'wiki', 'wikimenu']
```

However, I noticed that my version does't have a 'db' and my friends did but that might be because her auth = Auth(db) worked

**Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth` requires a `request` object, which is only available (1) within the web2py environment created when the framework receives an HTTP request, or (2) in a web2py shell. If you are simply in a standard Python shell or running a Python script/module outside of the web2py environment, there will be no `request` object available. In fact, you will also need `response`, `session`, and `T` objects to initialize `Auth`.

If you are working in a Python shell, your best option is to instead open a web2py shell:

```
> python web2py.py -S myapp/mycontroller -M
```

The above will open a Python shell but create a web2py environment in the context of myapp. The `-M` flag tells it to run the models for the app as well. With that option, you won't even need to define your `db` or initialize `Auth` because those objects will already be available in the shell environment (assuming they are defined in the app's models).

If necessary, you can also run an external script in a web2py environment using the `-R` flag (see the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Command-line-options) for more details).